# Parse.NET SDK v2.0 Xamarin Forms User SignUp Fail

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, parse-platform, parse-dotnet-sdk

i was using parse sdk v2.0 in a Xamarin Forms Shared Project.
I am trying to register a new user using Source: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/#basic-demonstration

Server
Parse Server version: 4.2.0
Host: Back4APP

Client
Parse .NET SDK version: -Version 2.0.0-develop-1
Xamarin.Forms Project .NET 2.1

```
      // Instantiate a ParseClient.
      ParseClient client = new ParseClient(back4app_app_id,"https://parseapi.back4app.com", clientKey);

      var instal = client.Services.GetCurrentInstallation();
      // Create a user, save it, and authenticate with it.
      await client.SignUpAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test");
```

await client.SignUpAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test");
throws following exception:
**System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.Parameter name: element'**

Stacktrace:

```
  at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttributes (System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/attribute.cs:857 
  at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute (System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType, System.Boolean inherit) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/attribute.cs:913 
  at System.Attribute.GetCustomAttribute (System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/attribute.cs:906 
  at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute (System.Reflection.Assembly element, System.Type attributeType) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs:10 
  at System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute[T] (System.Reflection.Assembly element) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/reflection/CustomAttributeExtensions.cs:27 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.HostManifestData.get_Inferred () [0x0000b] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub+<>c.<get_MetadataController>b__8_0 () [0x00005] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.Utilities.LateInitializer.GetValue[TData] (System.Func`1[TResult] generator) [0x0005b] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub.get_MetadataController () [0x00006] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub.<get_CommandRunner>b__22_0 () [0x0000c] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.Utilities.LateInitializer.GetValue[TData] (System.Func`1[TResult] generator) [0x0005b] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub.get_CommandRunner () [0x00006] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub.<get_UserController>b__36_0 () [0x00000] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.Utilities.LateInitializer.GetValue[TData] (System.Func`1[TResult] generator) [0x0005b] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.ServiceHub.get_UserController () [0x00006] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Abstractions.Infrastructure.CustomServiceHub.get_UserController () [0x00006] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.ParseUser+<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<SignUpAsync>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task _) [0x0000b] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at Parse.Infrastructure.Utilities.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0006d] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:108 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

  at Parse.Infrastructure.Utilities.InternalExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass7_0`1[TResult].<OnSuccess>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00033] in <12b98f4c44c343d5a566c90715f65c2c>:0 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromTask`1[TResult].InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/TaskContinuation.cs:108 
  at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs:2319 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

I cant find the Error.

Comment: Would you mind to share which line is throwing the error and the whole error stack?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo   Line   await client.SignUpAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test"); throws the error. I Edit the question

Comment: From your stack trace, it looks the problem is actually in the login line. Could you please try to change it to `await client.LogInAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test")`?

Comment: @DaviMacêdo i get the error already in the line 
      await client.SignUpAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test");
. That's why the program doesn't even run as far as the login. 
As a test I have removed the registration and only tried the login according to your specification.
changed
ParseUser user = client.LogInAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test").Result
to ParseUser user = await client.LogInAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test");

Error:

System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: element'
pretty much the same stacktrace

Comment: If you check the stack trace ` at Services.ParseService.Login () [0x00081]`, it looks about the login and not signup. Would you mind to share the updated code and error stack?

Comment: Sorry, was wrong trace. The right one is the same as in my question.....
The Code till it crash:
      ParseClient client = new ParseClient(back4app_app_id,back4app_server_url, clientKey);

      var instal = client.Services.GetCurrentInstallation();
//Here Throws the exception
        await client.SignUpAsync(username: "TestABC", password: "Test");

Comment: In this case could you please update the question with the correct error stack?

Comment: have adjusted the post so that it is a little clearer

Comment: Same thing if you remove `var instal = client.Services.GetCurrentInstallation();` ?

Comment: Yes same thing. I uploaded an example code: https://github.com/P0wmes/XamParseTest

Comment: Could you please try initializing this way? https://github.com/back4app/xamarin-quickstart-example/blob/36efc714ea0dffea0c9d568fb82c4648bd1a1d65/App1/MainActivity.cs#L19

Comment: I with Parse Version 2.0.0 the way to initializing  has changed? Can't use the example code because different version

Comment: It looks 2.0.0 is not stable yet. I'd try 1.8.0.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this post. There is a workaround for the issue (initialization code posted below). The workaround is described here: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-dotNET/issues/358

```
var m = new MetadataMutator
{
      EnvironmentData = new EnvironmentData { TimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.Local.StandardName },
      HostManifestData = new HostManifestData { Name = "Test", Identifier = "TestApp", ShortVersion = "1.0.0.0", Version = "1.0.0.0" }
};
ParseClient client = new ParseClient(new ServerConnectionData
{
       ApplicationID = "APP_ID",
       ServerURI = "SERVER_URI",
       Key = "APP_KEY"
},
new LateInitializedMutableServiceHub { MetadataController=m },
m
);
client.Publicize();
```